# PyAutoGui - screencapture: cannot write file to intended destination

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to find an image on my screen, however it it cannot seem to even save the screenshot? Any ideas?

**code:**

`pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/toolbox.jpg')`

**Error:**

```
 screencapture: cannot write file to intended destination, .screenshot2018-1106_00-06-22-111441.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dirk/Desktop/firsttry/test.py", line 103, in <module>
    a = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/toolbox.jpg')
  File "/Users/dirk/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 265, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
  File "/Users/dirk/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 331, in _screenshot_osx
    im = Image.open(tmpFilename)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2609, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.screenshot2018-1106_00-06-22-111441.png'
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/dirk/Desktop/firstry/test.py"]
[dir: /Users/dirk/Desktop/firsttry]
[path: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:~/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that I am using python version 3.7.1 but the folder doesnt direct to that?

Comment: If you are a beginner in Python you should start with something simpler: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yeah but that does not explain why it isn't working. I have enough coding background in other languages to understand the basics of python without going through it step by step.

Comment: Have you tried it with an absolute path for the screenshot file?

Comment: @MichaelButscher something like this?: `print(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.abspath("images\toolbox.jpg")))` It is returning `Cant find image`.

Comment: Don't use a backslash. If it doesn't work with forward slash either, try `print(os.path.abspath("images/toolbox.jpg"))` and check if the absolute path is the expected one.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Let me look into it closely again and Ill get back to you.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yeah with the absolute path, it is able to find the absolute path but once I add the `locateOnScreen` to it, then it gives me the same error.

Comment: There are two errors (from screencapture and then the `IOError`). Which one  (or both)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Both

Comment: Maybe try another destination (could be a missing permission) and maybe omit the leading `.` in the filename to write the screenshot file.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Is it possible to adjust the location the screencapture is saving to?

Comment: The [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-screenshot-function) of pyautogui tell you how.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ok so I am able to change the location of the screenshot. However when I run `locateOnScreen` it tries to take another screenshot and then it says it can not write to the intended location (no permission probably).

Comment: Once again look at the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions). There are multiple locate functions. Unfortunately it means more work to define the file location and then in the end remove the image but the responsible PyScreeze library was written too simple regarding the temporary file handling.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Getting some sleep and reading over the docs, finally figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Go to **pyscreeze/__init__.py** (located either in virutalenv or inside your python folder) file, **eg:** "/Users/dirk/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py"
- Navigate to **line 327 or 331**, inside function:  **def** **_screenshot_osx**
- **Remove the** **.** **symbol** in tempFilename = '.screenshot%s.png', so it should look like tempFilename = 'screenshot%s.png'

Comment: it can be a writing permission issue as well. In my case I have created a .app file using Py2App and when running the app it will try to create temp files in a folder without permissions, so to avoid that I included `/users/myuser/documents/` in front of `screenshot%s.png`